# Picking a video file from Gallery creates a blank screen in android

Tags: android

On selecting a video from Gallery creates a blank (black) screen before uploading to the firebase starts.  The upload succeeds, however, the blank screen freezes the app.
Here is my code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("video/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCodeForVideoPick);
```

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RequestCodeForVideoPick && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (data == null) {
            //Display an error
            return;
        }
 final Uri resultUri = data.getData();
 uploadTask = filePath.putFile(resultUri);

 //filePath firestorepath

...............
...............
}
```

It seems it is related to the file size. The video I am trying with is 7.5 MB.  Because when I pick an image with a similar code. I do not see any errors.

I tried using createChooser. I am getting the same result.

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "select video"), RequestCodeForVideoPick);
```

Edit 1: It seems like its happening because the video file is being picked from Google photos.

Edit 2: I tried loading a file from the Device. The black screen does not come up.

Please suggest any fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this library, It's lightweight and easy to use. It works well with Picture, Video, Audio, and File.

https://github.com/informramiz/AndroidFilePickerLibrary

Sample usage:

```
implementation 'io.github.informramiz:androidfilepickerlibrary:1.7'
```

And where you are picking video file use this:

```
FilePicker.showCameraPickerDialog(this);
```

The library will return the capture Picture, Video, Audio, and File.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //check if this result of AndroidFilePickerLibrary
        if (FilePicker.canHandleActivityResult(requestCode)) {
            //fetch the returned object
            FileInfo fileInfo = FilePicker.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            //show the UI in a TextView
            uriTextView.setText("Uri: " + fileInfo.getUri().toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this library. FileInfo fileinfo = FilePicker.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); returns null while data is not null. 
Moreover, it produces the same effect as using ExtraLocal in extra which is used to pick from the local device. The problem with that is it still shows google folder and if you click that folder you get a circular progress bar that does not stop.

Comment: please create the issue: https://github.com/informramiz/AndroidFilePickerLibrary/issues